# datetime.datetime.timedelta -- errors all permutations

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I am moving my working Python into somebody else's revised Python code. I get errors. I understand that datetime.datetime cause problems, but I think I have tried the permutations. In testing, if I return() before the lines below, no runtime error. I am sorry about the formatting in the post. I have not figured that out properly.

Python version 2.7.12

```
import os, sys, re, datetime
from datetime import datetime
```

**#NOTE: commenting out "from datetime import datetime" does not change the errors generated, so I think something is importing that from somewhere.**

These are the 3 versions and the resulting error message at run time"

```
dt = dt - datetime.timedelta(hours=24.5) # decrement date a day or two
```

gives error "type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'"

```
dt = dt - datetime.datetime.timedelta(hours=24.5) # ; also error:
```

gives error" type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'"

```
dt = dt - timedelta(hours=24.5) # ; also error:
```

gives error "global name 'timedelta' is not defined"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say that commenting out `from datetime import datetime` does not change the errors, but this shouldn't be the case, it is the cause of the problem.

`timedelta` is in the `datetime` module. However, because you have done `from datetime import datetime`, the name `datetime` in your namespace refers to the `datetime` class, not the module, and can't be used to directly get a handle on the `timedelta` class.

Removing this line, so that `datetime` refers to the module, you should be able to access it as `datetime.timedelta`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 24, 15, 10, 34, 942209)
>>> dt = dt - datetime.timedelta(hours=24.5)
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 23, 14, 40, 34, 942209)
```

Try it here: https://repl.it/KYDN/0

Alternatively, you could import both classes and refer to them directly:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> dt = datetime.now()
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 24, 15, 14, 46, 340878)
>>> dt = dt - timedelta(hours=24.5)
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 23, 14, 44, 46, 340878)
```

Comment: Thanks. I went with the "alternatively", and to further isolate my code from the stuff I am adding to, I used "from datetime import datetime , timedelta" inside of my function. I figure that will isolate my function from the code that I am sticking my function into. I did not know if that would work, but it was easy to just try it.

I am not object oriented. 

I don't understand all of what went on, but I understand that you provided a working solution for me!